# Why is the && operator is acting as || in this c code and vice versa?

Tags: c, conditional-statements, operators

I was Writing a program that prints all possible different combinations of two digits and in good formatting:

- Numbers must be separated by a comma and followed by a space except the last digit it should not be followed by a comma
- The two digits must be different
  upon writing the code I figured that to print out the desired output, it had to use two if statements that must be true at the same time, so naturally I used the "&&" operator but that gave something different so I tried the "||" and it worked.
  I just want to know what is what here and how they can be used with "!" operator if this is what is causing the issue.

When I used the && operator, this was the output (which is not the desired output):

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 0912, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 1923, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 2934, 35, 36, 37, 38, 3945, 46, 47, 48, 4956, 57, 58, 5967, 68, 6978, 7989
```

When I used the "||" operator I gave me this output (which is the desired one):

```
01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 08, 09, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 56, 57, 58, 59, 67, 68, 69, 78, 79, 89
```

Here is the code; the `if` statement is in line 16.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            if ( !(i >= j) )
            {
                putchar(i + 48);
                putchar(j + 48);
                if (i != 8 || j != 9)
                {
                    putchar(',');
                    putchar(' ');
                }
            }
        }        
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Obligatory: Don't use _magic numbers_ like `48` when you mean `'0'`. (There are simpler ways to print/suppress the 'comma space'... And, where's the `'\n'` to finish the output?)

Answer (score 3):

You want to print the `,`  unless both loops are on their last iteration.  That's the same as saying if either loop is not on its last iteration, which is what you're testing.

Consider

```
if (!(i == 8 && j == 9))
```

vs

```
if (i != 8 || j != 9)
```

which end up testing the same thing in different ways.

This ability to turn an "and" into an "or" by adding (or moving) "not" operations is called De Morgan's law.

Comment: thank you so much, this worked and now I get it.